# 9V battery open circuit 8.5 volts but reduces to 2V when connected in series with a 300 ohm resistor across the resistor. Why isn't it 8.5V?

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistors

I have tried with different batteries and the result is still same. I have cross-checked the multi-meter also, which works fine.

Disconnecting the resistor, and measuring the voltage again gives 8.5 volts value.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Thank you for the information. Could you formulate a question you want to have answered?

Comment: hey. So I wanted to know why it's behaving like this. If OCV is 8.5V then if I add one resistor, then across it also It should be around 8.5V right? What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit your question

Comment: Keyword for further reading: ESR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 9V battery is almost exhausted and has an internal resistance of about 1kΩ. A fresh battery would have an internal resistance maybe 1/500 of that.

So the circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsCaz2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage will always drop when you put a resistive load across a battery, but the amount can vary a lot.

Comment: Thanks. Will try with a fresh one.

Comment: another question I have is why doesn't the battery's internal resistance appear when we're testing open circuit voltage using multi-meter?

Comment: Because very little current is drawn out of the battery with the multimeter. It will also not appear if you increase your external resistance from 300 ohm to 30000 ohm.

Comment: See the above edit with the bottom schematic. The multimeter has a very high internal resistance (perhaps 10MΩ) so it behaves pretty much like an open circuit. Mathematically the voltage across the external resistor is Vmeter = Vbat * Rext/(Rext +Rint).  So if the internal resistance is high the meter reading will be low.

Comment: ohh. Got it. So battery's internal resistance along with the external resistor acts kind of like a voltage divider.

Comment: Exactly. Another point is that batteries tend to increase in internal resistance as they are exhausted but the open-circuit voltage does not change much until the very end. So a battery that can't run a motor could weakly supply a low-current LED for many more hours.